# Kubuntu Color Management: Can't change gamma, etc

Tags: kubuntu, kde, color-management

I recently switched from the Ubuntu 16.04 and the Unity desktop to Kubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to calibrate the monitor on my laptop (Thinkpad W520) with an i1 Display Pro and Display Cal.

When I try to change RGB values using Gamma those changes have no visible effect. I've looked over various fixes on the web, such as installing colord-kde but nothing seems to work. I've also seen it written that color management is simply broken on the KDE desktop, is this the case? Has anyone successfully created a profile using a colorimeter and used that profile with the above mentioned setup? I never had an issue calibrating Unity on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for the help!